# How to : on property value change of getComputedStyle(elm) , run a function , with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, data-binding

How can I have a function defined by me , run whenever a DOM element of my choice , has a property , of the object returned by getComputedStyle , changed .

Comment: Use getters/setters.

Comment: The [MutationObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might be interesting for you.

Comment: I mean, it really depends on what kind of changes you are trying to observe. Without your actual code we can only guess which approach would suit your needs. Hence I would suggest editing your question and showing us your code + an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @user1538301 can you please give an example ?

Comment: @icecub MutationObserver() is useful when the properties of the returned object by getComputedStyle are in the style attribute , something that is not always the case (for example inherited styles , width , height of flex or grid childs ) .

Comment: @icecub To be honest I just wanted to execute something on width change of a flex child . I can do that with resize observer but I just wonder why Object.observe was made obsolete ? What if I want to observe a change in my inherited styles , how can I observe that without obsolete Object.observe ? I think that things would have been much more simpler if that feature was not made obsolete .